# Polynomial approximation of a logarithm

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

This might be a silly question to ask but in the expansion of
 ln(1+x)=x-(x^2/2)+(x^3/3)-(x^4/4)...till infinity

The remainder term in the above expansion converges to zero as the number of terms increase
(So long as -1 < x <1).

When x>1, can it be shown with absolute certainty that the remainder would **always** blow up to infinity as the number of terms increase, thereby making the above approximation erroneous??

Comment: It lies inside the definition and the calculation of the radius of convergence for the function $\ln(1+x)$. For $x > 1$ there are other expansions for the logarithm.

Comment: @VonNeumann: I think you mean the radius of convergence of the power series on the right of the formula.

Comment: It isn't too difficult to give a closed form for the partial sums $x - x^2/2 + x^3/3 - \ldots \pm x^n/n$ from which you can see directly that the power series on the right of your formula diverges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$$
with

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}=1$$
the Radius of convergence is $R=1$.

For $x=1$, it is a convergent alternate series. It diverges as an harmonic series for $x =-1$.

Thus, the series converges only if $$-1< x \le 1$$